# Folding of Scala imports in Vim

Tags: scala, vim, folding

I'm trying to have my Vim setup automatically fold import statements when I open a Scala file. This is similar to what Intellij does when you open a file. I currently have the following lines in my `.vimrc` file from the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax_Fold_For_Java).

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldenable
syn region foldImports start=/(^\s*^import\) .\+/ end=/^\s*$/ transparent fold keepend
```

However when I open a `.scala` file it doesn't fold the imports but the body of objects. I am also using the [vim-scala plugin](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala). Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close to getting this to work. There are a few funky factors at play that we should consider.

- setting `foldmethod` to `syntax` (btw this is not documented on learn Vimscript the Hardway..so `:help foldmethod` was key to figure this out)

> SYNTAX                                          *fold-syntax*
>
> A fold is defined by syntax items that have the "fold" argument.
>   |:syn-fold|
>
> The fold level is defined by nesting folds.  The nesting of folds is
>   limited with 'foldnestmax'.
>
> Be careful to specify proper syntax syncing.  If this is not done
>   right, folds may differ from the displayed highlighting.  This is
>   especially relevant when using patterns that match more than one line.
>   In case of doubt, try using brute-force syncing:
>
> ```
>     :syn sync fromstart
> ```

The main thing to note is the `sync fromstart` this is a useful helper if you have regex that would match throughout the file and only want to catch the header. In your case you should be able to ignore this but just something to be aware of.

- top down regex scanning

Since the import block is fairly predictable we can simplify the `start` and `end` to look something like this:

```
syn region foldImports start="import" end=/import.*\n^$/ fold keepend
```

Since the `region` is just looking for some string to start the matching on we can just use `"import"`(or `/import/`) and then for the end value we want to use a little bit more carefully crafted statement. The key is that we want have the end be the *last* line of the import with a blank line following it (`/import.*\n^$/`)

Hopefully that does the trick for you (I do not work with scala so you may have to adjust the regex a bit as needed)

Comment: It is worth noting that if you turn off the option `syntax on` in your `.vimrc` the above code will work. However if it is on it will not fold properly.

Comment: The above statement is not correct. The problem resides in a plugin called [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose). If you remove it from Vim runtime the folds work as expected.